# How to extract custom extension's folder structure from a local magento installation?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have made a custom magento extension and i would like to upload it to a staging magento installation. The extension has no custom database entries/tables.

Is there a way to extract the extension's folder structure from local installation in order to upload these files only ?

Answer (score 0):

Manually copy the folders and files. Or suggest you setup a code repository system like github or subversion for your project and deploy the entire site onto the server from the repository so you can easily ensure that your staging environment is the same as your local copy. Makes managing code and updates really easy and also allows for developer collaboration.